# Running Cloud9 program for BeagleBone Black does nothing, then eventually stops at first line

Tags: beagleboneblack, cloud9-ide

I am using a BBB with the Debian distro. I access Cloud9 (192.168.7.2:3000) via Chrome on my Windows 7 machine. I am able to access existing demo js programs and have written a test program (myblink.js). The editor and overall system works fine.

But when I try to run the program, nothing happens for a few seconds, then eventually, it appears to stop on the first line (which becomes highlighted yellow). When this happens, the debugger panel pops out and the bottom window shows that the "debugger listening on port 15454" and I have the option to stop the program. At this point I can step through the program, well, at least to the point where there is some asynchronous events handling required.

However, if I run "node myblink.js" app from the bash tab in Cloud9 or from a shell (via putty) it works perfectly fine.

Do I have to set anything up to enable debugging? Or is it too much to expect from the debugger and a BBB system?

Comment: The debugger actually seems to work fine from the description you're giving. My guess is the setting for "Pause on Exceptions" is enabled (the round button on the right top of the debugger) and then the debugger is triggered on the first line. You can also disable the debugger altogether when running by disabling the little 'bug' icon in the Runner panel on the bottom.

Comment: I'm not sure that's it. According to the UI, I have the following settings "Deactivate all Breakpoints" and "Don't pause on exceptions". With the bug icon enabled, the debugger appears to stop on the first line, with the bug icon disabled, program runs fine.

Comment: Can you share the code where the debugger halts, and a screenshot of when this happens?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1unwrl26hgl4vo7/cloud9%20debugging%20not%20working.png?dl=0

Comment: We suspect this is a bug in the version of Cloud9 that got shipped with the BeagleBone, which has been resolved since. We're  contacting the BB maintainers to provide an update of the IDE with the next BB update. I don't have any timeframe for that yet though.

Comment: Thanks, Ivar - I'll keep an eye on this.